# The implementation about Hyperledger Fabric Table

Tags: hyperledger

I would like to create a table to store data and then according to a key like "lisa" to get all the lisa's data.There are 4 validation peers in the network. If I insert a row data to the table by `InsertRow` in my chaincode, will there be four row of data inserted into the table?

Comment: First of please let us know which language you're coding your chaincode in?
Java or Go?

Comment: I use golang to code the chaincode

Answer (score 0):

there will be only one row inserted into the table. This row will be copied by transaction propagation to each of the validation peers. So by making a query of the table on any validation peer you will get only one row.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Willson, if this answer did help, then why not mark it as the answer?